# SQL insert row with one change

Tags: sql, select, insert

I have this table:

```
Table1:
id   text
1     lala
```

And i want take first row and copy it, but the id 1 change to 2.
Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kate - Gordon's answer is technically correct.  However, I would like to know more about *why* you want to do this.

If you're intent is to have the field increment with the insertion of each new row, manually setting the id column value isn't a great idea - it becomes very easy for there to be a conflict with two rows attempting to use the same id at the same time.

I would recommend using an IDENTITY field for this (MS SQL Server -- use an AUTO_INCREMENT field in MySQL).  You could then do the insert as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (text)
SELECT text 
FROM Table1
WHERE id = 1
```

SQL Server would automatically assign a new, unique value to the id field.

Answer (score 3):

A SQL table has no concept of "first" row.  You can however select a row based on its characteristics.  So, the following would work:

```
insert into Table1(id, text)
    select 2, text
    from Table1
    where id = 1;
```

As another note, when creating the table, you can have the id column be auto-incremented.  The syntax varies from database to database.  If `id` were auto-incremented, then you could just do:

```
insert into Table1(text)
    select text
    from Table1
    where id = 1;
```

And you would be confident that the new row would have a unique id.